# Scroll up if page becomes shorter than current scroll position (bootstrap + jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to approach this problem?:

I have a list that has names which you can click on. When you click on the name, the list disappears and information about that name appears. However, that list is often longer than the information, so if you click on a name toward the bottom of the list... the list is replaced with the information (so the page gets shorter). However, Chrome (on OS X 10.8) keeps the current scroll position even though the scrollbar has shrunk... so a user will see just a gray screen (because the page no longer goes that far down).

**Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can clarify the question if needed :)**

**Edit:** I had previously tried what AwokeKnowing suggested, but it's not a great option because if the added content is already in the viewport scrolling to the top has a "jerky" feeling to it. You can already see it being added, so why adjust the scroll in that case? There needs to be a way to test if the content is visible in the viewport or not.

```
$("button").click(function(){
   alert($("div").scrollTop());
});
```

Also, AwokeKnowing also suggested this may simply be a browser bug. If that's the case, is there a work around?

**Edit 2:** More specifics, the names are a list of links (`<a href="#">`) in a bootstrap tab-pane and clicking on them creates a new tab-pane and switches to it. The issue is that the newly created pane is significantly shorter than the one with the list on it. Switching to the shorter pane creates the unwanted behavior.

Comment: Questions on SO work best when you post code that you have tried. Here is more reference on how to ask questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Andrew that's a start but an example we could look at that demonstrates the "jerky" feeling would be helpful..  Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrates it?

Comment: pictures would have been nice :), if not the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jquery you can scroll to any element, so just scroll top your div when you handle the click

```
$("button").click(function(){
   alert($("div").scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! :) Is there a way to check whether or not the user's view is past the end of the page? I wouldn't want it to scroll to the top if it's not necessary.

Comment: well, that's actually a browser bug, so there "shouldn't" be a way.

Comment: shouldn't you always scroll to the top of the new item you just added?

Comment: Thank you again for you reply! The reason I don't want it always scrolling me to the top is because if the added content is visible in the viewport then forcing a scroll has a bit of a "jerky" feeling to it. Did that make sense?

Comment: what code are you using to hide all the names?  what kind of an element are they in?  (this is why they suggested you add your current code)

Comment: The names are a list of links, clicking the name creates a new bootstrap content tab and switches to it. So basically the tab-pane I'm switching from is significantly longer than the tab-pane I'm switching to.

Comment: that's interesting. I wonder if boostrap is just putting the tab behind something, or in other words, pre-allocating vertical space for the longest tab.  if you scroll up, then can you scroll back down to the "grey" area?

Comment: Once you scroll out of the "grey" area, you can't scroll back.

Comment: this does seem to be a browser bug, and these things we work around via hacks.  I mean literally when they click, count up the number of elements in the list, read the current scroll position, do the math and decide whether to scroll to the top or not.   websites are full of this and it is very annoying, but it's getting better these days.